# what is equivalent with sequelize-auto in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, sequelize-auto

I want to implement database schema work in mysqlworkbench and sync the database model to spring framework with JPA. I did the same when I made server side application with Node.js. by using sequelize-auto as below command.

```
sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database name> -u <user name> -p <port> -o <path> -x password -e mysql
```

I want to know if there is same or similar way to work in JAVA spring frame work with JPA.

Comment: sequelize-auto generates one class per table without relationships, right?

Comment: sequelize-auto generates models with relationships.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools

Comment: Thanks a lot @SimonMartinelli . I just started to learn Java with spring framework. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'm going to add this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Hibernate Tools here:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools